# Inverse Kinematics Issue

Tags: bones, inverse-kinematics

[image]I am fairly new at using Blender and I am currently trying to learn how to rig my modeled guy I downloaded off the internet. I was able to rig my guy's leg and is moving smoothly, but when I tried to use inverse kinematics on the arm, it went berserk. It seemed that when I applied the "Inverse Kinematics" operation to the bone, it showed an orange line attached from the bone to the abdomen, and I know that this is what is causing the problem. I have tried everything to remove it. I tried clearing the parent on this using pose and edit mode but nothing is working. Can anyone help? (Picture attached)

Comment: That dotted line is normal. It visually indicates where a connection of some kind lies between two objects. Typically it's a parenting relationship. In this case, it is a representation of the IK solver. It draws a line to the top bone in the IK chain. Now, it's odd to me that you have bad behavior already, because according to your screenshot, you have yet to choose a pole vector AND you have yet to choose the armature object as a target, also. Until those things happen, the IK doesn't have enough information to do anything, good or bad. So when exactly did it start going berzerk?

Comment: It actually started to go berzerk after I assigned both its target and pole target. This was my second attempt. My first attempt did not have the orange dotted line and it turned out to be fine. I assigned the target to the hand controller and the pole target to the bone behind the elbow to allow a total movement of all the bones in the arm. However, the orange dotted line appeared this time, and now the arm is jank.

Comment: So what happens if you delete the IK constraint and start over?

Comment: Nevermind, I actually figured it out. My chain length was set to zero, in which attached the orange dotted line to another part of the body but I needed it to attach to the arm, so I set the chain length to 2 and it works smoothly now.